# Trying to get Spring Webflow Travel Sample With the PrimeFaces Components working

Tags: spring-mvc, primefaces, spring-webflow

Trying to get Spring Webflow Travel Sample With the PrimeFaces Components working:

The following are the steps I am taking:

```
svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/webflow-primefaces-showcase
cd webflow-primefaces-showcase
mvn package
```

then I had to add the following to the POM.XML

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but now I am getting the following on the first screen:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. I dont know it if its the best what but I had to change all the

**http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui**

to

**http://primefaces.org/ui"**